# cannot compile scala test with intellij 14.1

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

The project uses scala 2.9

my scalatest dependency is:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest_2.9.2</artifactId>
    </dependency>


Error:scalac: Error: org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.ServerException
Error compiling sbt component 'compiler-interface-2.9.2-50.0'
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:145)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:142)
    at sbt.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:285)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:142)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:139)
    at sbt.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:285)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$.compileSources(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:139)
    at sbt.compiler.IC$.compileInterfaceJar(IncrementalCompiler.scala:33)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$.org$jetbrains$jps$incremental$scala$local$CompilerFactoryImpl$$getOrCompileInterfaceJar(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:87)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$$anonfun$getScalac$1.apply(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:44)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$$anonfun$getScalac$1.apply(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:43)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.getScalac(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:43)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.createCompiler(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:22)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory$$anonfun$createCompiler$1.apply(CachingFactory.scala:24)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory$$anonfun$createCompiler$1.apply(CachingFactory.scala:24)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache$$anonfun$getOrUpdate$2.apply(Cache.scala:20)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache.getOrUpdate(Cache.scala:19)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory.createCompiler(CachingFactory.scala:23)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:22)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.make(Main.scala:62)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:20)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:319)
```

Comment: This looks like it has nothing to do with ScalaTest, but simply the IntelliJ IDEA plugin perhaps not supporting Scala 2.9.2? Could you use Scala 2.10 in your project? 2.9.2 is pretty old now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your dependency is incomplete and misses the library version. Easiest is to [look it up on Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.scalatest|scalatest_2.9.2|1.9.2|jar):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalatest_2.9.2</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version> <!-- here -->
</dependency>
```